# Which file do I need to edit to implement a 'Back to top' link?

Tags: 6, theming

I am running a Drupal 6.22 site, with a custom template installed in /sites/all/themes/mytheme. Which template file should I edit to implement a back to top link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where you want the link to be, but your best bets would probably be `page.tpl.php`, `node.tpl.php` or a variation of those templates (specific to content types, etc).

For more on templates see [Drupal 6 template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642)

Comment: I've added `<a href="#top">Back to top</a>` to a block called content bottom, but I'm not sure where to put the named anchor. Is it best practice to create a template suggestion or edit page.tpl.php?

Comment: Again, it depends where you want this functionality. If you want say, `<div id="top"></div>` on every page, then place it in page.tpl.php, if you want the anchor to be inside the content, place it in a node.tpl.php

Comment: Added `<?php l('link', '',  array('fragment' => 'top', 'external' => TRUE)); ?>` to said file, which worked as required.